# Call function onclick submit button on instant message javascript app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the current progress I have done on this instant message web

```html
<input name="chang" id="textInput" class="input responsive-column"
       placeholder="Please enter your message here" type="text"
       onkeydown="ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)">
```

Which will send the message dynamically when I press the Enter Key on the keyboard, but I want to also make a button which will do the same function as well, I have already tried to put the input and a submit button in a form but it will refresh the whole page.

```html
    <input type="submit" value="send" onclick=""/>
```

Any suggestion for me? Thanks.

kind regards

Comment: use preventDefault() for submitting form

Answer (score 0):

Change the type with `button` instead of `submit`

```
 <input type="button" value="send" onclick="$('#textInput').trigger('keydown')"/>
```

**OR**

use `preventDefault()` function for preventing the page refresh

```
<input type="submit" value="send" onclick="event.preventDefault(),$('#textInput').trigger('keydown')"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for being ignorance, how can I link this input button to the input field? Since on the current status I use inputKeyDown(event, this); thanks

Comment: @Mr.Beginner check my updated answer.it will help you

Comment: I have tried to do this, but the send button still do not do any function, any ideas?

Comment: <input type="button" value="send" onclick="ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, $('#textInput')[0])"/>

Comment: @Mr.Beginner .oh sry its keydown event .you call the direct keydown event from the click.See the updated

Comment: The send button still not working, i have no idea why, the current text field is

 <input name="chang" id="textInput" class="input responsive-column"
       placeholder="Please enter your message here" type="text"
       onkeydown="ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)">

The current send button is 

 <input type="button" value="send" onclick="$('#textInput').trigger('keydown')"/>

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: check the idname of `textInput`. duplicate of the same id name is not working.just change with new  idname and try again

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like `onclick="$('#textInput').trigger('keydown')"`

It will trigger the `keydown` function you have in your `textInput` element

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="chang" id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" placeholder="Please enter your message here" type="text" onkeydown="console.log('textInput is triggered')">

<input type="button" value="send" onclick="$('#textInput').trigger('keydown')" />
```

Comment: I have tried it, but the button still does nothing, any ideas?